# all permutations of a string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have gotten the code for all permutations of a string from another user on stackoverflow and i am trying to make it work in my webpage. Are there any problems with this code? I get an error in the javascript console when i try to submit a word. The error flashes for a short time so i cannot read it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#anagram').submit(function(event) {


function findAllPermutations(str, index, buffer) {
    if (typeof str == "string") {
        str = str.split("") }; 
    if (typeof index == "undefined") {
        index = 0 };
    if (typeof buffer == "undefined") {
        buffer = [] };
    if (index >= str.length) {
        return buffer };
    for (var i = index; i < str.length; i++) {
        buffer.push(ToggleLetters(str, index, i));
    }
    return FindAllPermutations(str, index + 1, buffer);
}

function ToggleLetters(str, index1, index2) {
    if (index1 != index2) {
        var temp = str[index1]
        str[index1] = str[index2]
        str[index2] = temp
    };
    return str.join("");
}



        list = $('input#word').val();
        $('#resulttext').append("<p>" + findAllPermutations(list) + "</p>")
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts3.js"></script>
    <title>Anagram finder</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="band">
            <h1>Anagram Finder</h1>
        </div>

        <form id="anagram">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="word">Your Word</label>
                    <input id="word" type="text">

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">Find!</button>
        </form>
        <div id="resulttext">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error? Did you try any debugging based on what the error says?

Comment: in your code `findAllPermutations` should be `FindAllPermutations` (with capital F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a mistake in the function name and as event.preventDefault() was at the end of the function, you wan not being able to see the error as the page was being refreshed.

Try it:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <title>Anagram finder</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form#anagram').submit(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                function findAllPermutations(str, index, buffer) {
                    if (typeof str == "string") {
                        str = str.split("") }; 
                    if (typeof index == "undefined") {
                        index = 0 };
                    if (typeof buffer == "undefined") {
                        buffer = [] };
                    if (index >= str.length) {
                        return buffer };
                    for (var i = index; i < str.length; i++) {
                        buffer.push(ToggleLetters(str, index, i));
                    }
                    return findAllPermutations(str, index + 1, buffer);
                }

                function ToggleLetters(str, index1, index2) {
                    if (index1 != index2) {
                        var temp = str[index1]
                        str[index1] = str[index2]
                        str[index2] = temp
                    };
                    return str.join("");
                }



                list = $('input#word').val();
                $('#resulttext').append("<p>" + findAllPermutations(list) + "</p>")

            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="band">
            <h1>Anagram Finder</h1>
        </div>

        <form id="anagram">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="word">Your Word</label>
                <input id="word" type="text">

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">Find!</button>
        </form>
        <div id="resulttext">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```